# Google Drive(Picker) not showing All Files after successful login

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-picker

I've got a few problem with Google Picker that I just can't seems to solve.

When I click on google picker and Login Window came for Sign In.

After Signed In by entering the credential it always show the default screen which contains only one file for the google drive it is not showing other files. If I login with any account it still shows the same file. please see the screen shot.

[Google Drive File Picker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SJVC.png)

I have used react-google-picker for this. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-picker

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried logging out off ALL google accounts, and removing your Google cookies from the browser before trying with the account owning the drive that you want to access?

Comment: Can you show your code?? **DONT FORGET**  to remove sensitive info!